# R code for Granger representation theorem of VECM model

Tags: r, vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

Is there any R package or code snippet to obtain **the Granger representation of a Vector Error Correction Model** (VECM) as describe in [HANSEN, 2005](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1368-423X.2005.00149.x) ?

The VECM model would be the output of `tsDyn::VECM` or `urca::cajorls`.

Reference:

P. R., HANSEN. *Granger's representation theorem: A closed-form expression for I(1) proccesses*, 2005. Econometrics Journal (8): 23-38.

Comment: May I ask why you need it for? They way I see it, asking for this is, in a way, similar to ask for a code that would rewrite a stable VAR into a VMA, for which the applications lie mainly on calculating impulse-responses - something that is straightforward to get from the packages you mentioned.

Comment: I want to get the trend and cycle components and use the trend component as an input for another application (compute deviation between trend and observed values)